# LibreOffice Calc - view the zoom button

Tags: libreoffice-calc

I am using the Spanish versión but it should be the same thing.

I need tot see the Zoom button on the top of the window - under the menu - I don't know how that area is called.

Answer (score 3):

1. Go to Tools -> Customize
2. Select Toolbars.
3. Search for "Zoom"

[image]

- Click on the right arrow button. Click <kbd>OK</kbd>.

OR

Follow steps 1 & 2, then on the "Assigned Commands" pane, look for "Zoom". Select it and click on <kbd>OK</kbd>.

[image]

The zoom button will appear on the toolbar.

[image]